# Назовите пожалуйста причины из-за которых может не работать CSS код?

Tags: css

Я учу CSS. Выучил HTML и знаю как подключать CSS файл , но некоторые теги написанные в таблице каскадных стилей просто-напросто не работают, сколько бы я раз не обновлял страницу.

Вот пример, вроде все правильно. Помогите пожалуйста !!!

```css
p.sub {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  vertical-align: sub;
  color: chocolate;
  text-align: center;
}

p.super {
  vertical-align: super;
}

p.pixel {
  vertical-align: -15px;
}
```

```html
<p class='sub'>ТЕКСТ #1</p>
<br>
<p class='super'>ТЕКСТ #2</p>
<br>
<p class='pixel'>ТЕКСТ #3</p>
```

Comment: Ну, а вы html то добавьте)

Comment: какой именно из тегов у вас не срабатывает?

Comment: укажите, что должно быть по вашему мнению. То, что что-то не срабатывает нам ничего не дает.

Comment: чтобы работал vertical-align нужно сделать елемент строчно-блочным(inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом вы можете использовать `vertical-align`

```css
div {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  color: chocolate;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub {
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.super {
  vertical-align: super;
}

.pixel {
  vertical-align: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Default / <span class='sub'>ТЕКСТ #1</span>
</div>
<div>
  Default / <span class='super'>ТЕКСТ #1</span>
</div>
<div>
  Default / <span class='pixel'>ТЕКСТ #1</span>
</div>
```